# Angular Material 2: Add mat-error within a mat-checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm wondering if it is possible to add validation error message (mat-error) for a checkbox for example including the required validation.

```
<mat-checkbox [formControl]="formControl">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-checkbox>
<mat-error *ngIf="formControl.hasError('required')">
```

Comment: How can a checkbox be in error ? And no it's not possible for all I know.

Comment: @user4676340  **"You must agree to the terms of conditions"** is a common case, where a checkbox is in error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well a weird work around - I actually needed the form-field-lable but it also works for the mat-error - is using an input of type check-box inside of the form-field while hiding the input that is connected to the form, something like this:

```
<mat-form-field  appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>check</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="check" [hidden]="true">
    <input (change)="check()" type="checkbox">
    <mat-error>{{ getErrorForCheck() }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Ya, its ugly, but for keeping my form with labels(or errors) for check-box I use it.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:

> **mat-form-field** : Error messages can be shown under the form field underline by adding mat-error elements inside the form field.

mat-error cannot be added to a checkbox

Comment: Thank you, is there any workaround or UX design to include errors messages for checkbox?

Comment: the gotcha being that as of June 2018 it's not possible to place a mat-checkbox inside of a mat-form-field: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7891

Answer (score 4):

Workaround for adding error handling to Checkbox:

```
<mat-checkbox 
   formControlName="agreeConditions" 
   [ngClass]="{'errorCheckbox': checkBoxError}"
>I agree
</mat-checkbox>

<mat-error *ngIf="checkBoxError">
   {{errorMessage}}
</mat-error>
```

You can insert a Function for checkBoxError as well. Change the var "checkBoxError" to a function call getCheckBoxError()

component.ts Function:

```
getCheckBoxError() {
if(this.formGroup.touched) {
  const value = this.formGroup.get('agreeConditions').invalid;
//You can call .hasError('required') as well!
  return value;
}
return false;
}
```

Cheers